# Why isn't multer uploading my image with storage option?

Tags: node.js, multer

Multer is able to upload my file, but only if I use the dest option. When I use diskStorage, it doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, so feel free to correct me. Here is my code...

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "/uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post('/signup', upload.single("avatar"), (req, res, next) => {

  console.log(req.file);

  const { heroname, pass, pass2 } = req.body;

  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(12);
  const hashedPassWord = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, salt);

  User.create({
    name: heroname,
    password: hashedPassWord
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Task complete!');
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      next(err);
    })

});
```

And here is the associated HTML...

```
      <div class="form-item">
    <label for="avatar">Choose your Avatar:</label>
    <input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" accept="image/*">
  </div>
```

When I log the req.file to the console, it shows the correct information. When I look inside the uploads folder, nothing uploads.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed a `./` for my uploads folder file path, not a `/`.